# Retreive BLOB from Database with image Using Spring MVC and Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, html, blob, thymeleaf

I have some problems presenting an image on frontend using spring mvc with hibernate to retrieve the image stored into a blob on database.

Entity:

```
@Lob
@Column(length = 100000)
private byte[] foto;

public byte[] getFoto() {
    return foto;
}

public void setFoto(byte[] foto) {
    this.foto = foto;
}
```

Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/view")
    public ModelMap viewVehicle(@RequestParam(value = "id", required = false) Vehicle vehicle, Model model) {
        if (vehicle == null) {
            vehicle = new Vehicle();
        }

        return new ModelMap("vehicle", vehicle);
    }
```

HTML:

```
<img th:src="*{'data:image/png;base64,'+ foto}" />
```

But the view run without error's but the image not displayed.

I experimented a lot of solutions i've found on internet, but anything worked.

Any consideration to help-me resolve this situation?

Greetings

Comment: Are you sure that `foto` holds base64 encoded image data? Which version of Thymeleaf are you using? And please post the entire view code; origin of `foto` variable is unclear. Another thing that is suspicious to me is that maybe your `vehicle` is always `null` and your are returning a new (blank) instance of Vehicle. That might be the case that you are not seeing the image. Please debug that situtation.

Comment: have u found the answer? if not i can help

Answer (score 0):

Please try converting image `byte[]` data to base64 encoded string with the following code.

You can either do it in the Entity by defining a new property or you can do it in the Controller before returning your ModelMap.

```
String base64EncodedImage = Base64.encodeBase64String(foto);
```

Then you can refer to this new variable in your view:

```
<img th:src="*{'data:image/png;base64,'+ base64EncodedImage}" />
```

Please note that in order to use `Base64.encodeBase64String()` method you should `import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64`